# How to rollback changes made to a object in silverlight 3 with a TwoWay binding

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, binding

I have a Silverlight 3 project.  I have a textbox that is TwoWay data bound to an object.  If the user wants to cancel the changes that they made to the textbox, what is the best way to undo the changes to the bound field on the object?

I know I could store the initial value in a separte variable when the object is loaded, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to roll back when the value is set, then throw an exception in the property setter.
If you need to do rollback on submit, then you should store the settings in a separate class and provide atomic setting and rollback - make sure that each of your properties support INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 5):

The example implementation of `IEditableObject` on MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx)) shows a pretty straightforward way to accomplish it.  I think this implementation is a little clearer, but on the other hand Microsoft probably tested theirs:

```
public class MyObject : ViewModelBase, IEditableObject
{
   private struct MyData
   {
      string Foo,
      string Bar
   };

   private MyData Saved = new MyData()
   private MyData Current = Saved;

   public string Foo
   {
      get { return Current.Foo; }
      set
      {
         Current.Foo = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
      }
   }

   public string Bar
   {
      get { return Current.Bar; }
      set
      {
         Current.Bar = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
      }
   }


   public void BeginEdit() 
   { 
      if (Current == Saved)
      {
         Current = new MyData(); 
         Current.Foo = Saved.Foo;
         Current.Bar = Saved.Bar;
      }
   }

   public void CancelEdit() 
   {
      if (Current != Saved)
      { 
         Current = Saved;
         OnPropertyChanged("Foo");
         OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
      }
   }

   public void EndEdit()
   {
      if (Current != Saved)
      {
         Saved = Current;
      }
   }
}
```

Using this pattern, `Current` always contains the current values of the object irrespective of its editing state, which makes the property accessors easy to implement; the `IEditableObject` methods just switch around what `Current` is.

It's reasonably easy to implement even a quite large number of properties; you just have to be sure to update `BeginEdit` and `CancelEdit` when you add a new property.